# Why isn't the color palette applied in seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

When plotting histplot, I can't apply the color palette, to have each be a different color in the histogram. What's the problem? In other plottings, the palette works. Here is my code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
sns.histplot(x='age', data=df, bins = 20)
sns.color_palette('plasma', as_cmap=True)
plt.show()
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `sns.color_palette` returns a list of colours; you need to specify that the plot should render with those specific colours.

Comment: It is for histplot that this does not work, the graph remains the standard blue color.

Comment: Histplot only supports coloring different hue categories. You could use np.histogram to calculate the values and then plot via sns.barplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the palette in the same visual:

```
cm = sns.color_palette("plasma",20) #Splitting the palette in the same amount of numbers bins
    
# Plot histogram.
plot = sns.histplot(x='age',data=df, bins=20)

for bin_,i in zip(plot.patches,cm):
    bin_.set_facecolor(i)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It is for histplot that this does not work, the graph remains the standard blue color.

Comment: How do you expect the graph colors to be changed? Because if you use `color='red'` then all bars will be red. Given it is a histogram, what should the palette represent, different bins? Height?

Comment: I wanted to get bins in different colors.

Comment: Please take a look at my edited answer.